# GBoard multi-language keyboard layout

Tags: gboard

I'm using 4 languages for writing on my phone on a daily basis. One of them is German. They use the qwertz layout by default.

I have set the German keyboard layout to qwerty in settings, but this setting only seems to work, when multi-language is disabled. When German is the first of the 3 currently enabled languages, the layout changes to qwertz, which is annoying, because I'm used to qwerty. Same with the special characters after a long press, only the special characters of the first language are shown.

How can I solve the two problems? Any ideas?